# how do i pull a report using sql

Tags: sql

i exported the below report from the server where the plan id is covered for benefitcodeid  = 39

```
SELECT *
FROM plan_benefitcode b
  JOIN plans p on b.planid=p.planid
WHERE benefitcodeid  = 39
```

Know how do i get the report where the planid is not covered for benefitcodeid  = 39

Comment: I don't understand the question, did you mean executing the same query where benefitcodeid  is not 39?

Comment: The benefitcodeid is 39 but the planid is not covered for the benefitcodeid 39

Comment: how do i write this plans without 39 = all plans - plans with 39

Comment: Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (no images.) Simplify if possible. A.k.a. [mcve].

Comment: As others have pointed out, make a MRE.  You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to build a little fake place for us to see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM plans p
WHERE Not Exists
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM plan_benefitcode b
    WHERE b.planid = p.planid
    And b.benefitcodeid  = 39
)
```

[EXISTS (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#e-using-not-exists)

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard, exactly what i need.